# SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: oracle

Here is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE (
    SCHEDULE_ID INT                NOT NULL
    ,ARRV_TIME  INT                NOT NULL
    ,DEP_TIME   INT                NOT NULL
    ,BUS_TRANSFERS  VARCHAR2(40)   NOT NULL
    ,BUS_ID  NUMERIC               NOT NULL
    ,TRAVEL_DIRECTION  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,WEEK_DAY  INTEGER             NOT NULL
);
```

I run this insert statement

```
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE (SCHEDULE_ID, ARRV_TIME, DEP_TIME, BUS_TRANSFERS, BUS_ID, TRAVEL_DIRECTION, WEEK_DAY) 
VALUES (SEQ_SCHEDULE.NEXTVAL,'10', '11', 'White Oak', '2', 'North', '4');
```

and I get this error message:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - INSERT INTO SCHEDULE
>   (SCHEDULE_ID, ARRV_TIME, DEP_TIME, BUS_TRANSFERS, BUS_ID,
>   TRAVEL_DIRECTION, WEEK_DAY) VALUES (SEQ_SCHEDULE.NEXTVAL,'10', '11',
>   'White Oak', '2', 'North', '4')
>
> Error report - SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: Works just fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6a1a4/1 Although this is *not* causing your  problem, single quotes should never be used around numbers. They are only for character values.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE( 
SCHEDULE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
ARRV_TIME INTEGER NOT NULL ,
DEP_TIME INTEGER NOT NULL ,
BUS_TRANSFERS VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ,
BUS_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
TRAVEL_DIRECTION VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL ,
WEEK_DAY INTEGER NOT NULL );

INSERT INTO SCHEDULE(SCHEDULE_ID, ARRV_TIME, DEP_TIME,BUS_TRANSFERS,BUS_ID, TRAVEL_DIRECTION, WEEK_DAY)
VALUES(SEQ_SCHEDULE.NEXTVAL,10,11, 'White Oak',2,'North',4);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you have declared arrived_time as int and you are trying to insert '10' value for that. Which is a string please remove the quotes for non string data types